Why is too large of a JDBC fetch size bad for performance?
Documentation regarding JDBC fetch size often says that increasing it improves performance but setting it too high can decrease performance. It also applies to JPA as it is just a utility library build on top of JDBC.
Such as here for example https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLJPA/q_jdbc_fetch_size.htm#TLJPA647

I fail to understand why. If the query result is 10k rows and my fetch size is 1M what is the problem with that? I get my 10k rows with one request to DB server.

"setting it too high can decrease performance" -- That's not what it says. It says "setting a fetch size too large or too small can decrease performance".

You'd have to run performance tunning tests to see it, but networks/connections don't always like extremely large chunks of data; bigger isn't always better, but it depends on your network and system to find the optimal sizes.

Setting the fetch size is a tradeoff between getting enough rows to make the wait/roundtrip delay worthwhile (e.g. fetching 1 by 1 might have the same delay as fetching 100 at a time), and not fetching too many rows that you're blocked waiting for all those rows to be received (e.g. fetching 1000 rows might take as long as or longer than 10x fetching 100 rows), making your application less responsive and/or using a lot more memory to store those rows locally, which can add additional garbage collection overhead.
To recap, a too large batch size might be bad for performance because:

It can increase the time to fetch rows (more network round trips)
It can result in more memory consumption to store all those rows locally, and thus more garbage collection (and if memory is tight, it can also result in more repeated full garbage collection to try and free up memory, slowing down your application even further)
It could tie up resources on your database server, reducing throughput for other clients (though this impact may vary per DBMS)

Also, for user interactive applications, they might not even consult all rows, so fetching them all might be wasteful if they're never going to be consulted.
Also, for user interactive applications, a smaller fetch size might be slower overall, but the duration of individual fetches might be better for the responsiveness (e.g. though those 100x fetches of 10 rows, or 10x fetches of 100 rows might be slower than 1x fetch of 1000 rows, it makes your application respond faster and thus provide a better user experience).

Thanks. I came to the same conclusion by now. So when my client needs to load 1M rows and only then can start processing I better set the fetch size to 1M. My client will observe a high latency but after that has fast processing because everything is in memory. On the other hand my client can be optimized for throughput. Load first chunk of 1000 rows. While this is processed asynchronously load the next 1000 rows. Here I set a small fetch size of 1000.
